# Create Windows 8 recovery parition on other hard disk

Tags: windows, partitioning

I've bought an Optical Hard Disk bay to increase space storage of my laptop and now I haven't any way to reinstall my operating system if one day it becomes unusable.
So, I tried to create a recovery parition using the method I saw worked on other computers :

1. Created a new parition (V:)
2. Copy Windows Setup files on V:
3. Open Administrator CMD :

   1. V:
   2. cd boot
   3. bootsect.exe /nt60 V:
4. Mark partition active

I'm using Windows 8 RTM (MSDN) and I try to do it on a second Hard Disk.
The thing is, it doesn't work. Parition is unbootable. When I select the hard disk on the BIOS Popup menu it just skip it to the main disk, the one where Windows 8 is.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to backup your OS seems like a hack.  A better way might be to use software that is designed for just that purpose.

[Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) works great for moving images from one disk to another.  With a bootable Acronis disk you could create a backup image of the hard drive with Windows 8 RTM installed on it. Then, restore the image to another hard drive.  Acronis will let you set the partition size during the restore process among other options.

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to do. It's not a hack, if you can create a bootable USB Stick, why not a partition on a hard-drive ?
I don't want to call a third-party software.